# Rolar página após carregar o $(document) com jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como rolar automaticamente a página suavemente para 400 pixels abaixo do topo ao carregar a página com jQuery com scrollTop(); ?

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        // ROLAR A PAGINA
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi assim:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: 320
        }, 1600);
    });
</script>
```

Ao carregar a página, rola automaticamente 320 pixels para baixo suavemente em 1600ms.